# How to hollow complicated inner surface?

Tags: 3d-printing

I am conducting research on salivary gland bioprinting. I have developed a solid structure of a 3D model representing the salivary gland, and now I need to create a hollow inner lumen within this structure. As a result, the thickness of the wall will not be uniform, as the size of the lumen may vary as it approaches certain areas. I am wondering if there is a method or tool available to create a complex hollow inner surface, as the solidify tool can only achieve simple hollowing.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a clue about the general characteristics of your outer model? Solidify can have variable thickness, controlled by vertex group. That can be painted in, or controlled by texture. You can model / sculpt the inner surface, (perhaps initially derived from the outer surface) independently.  How you do this partly depends on the final purpose of your model. (Illustrate with an image?)

Comment: Sure!. If you google salivary gland morphology the first picture that looks like a hand is what my outer model look like. The lumen in the picture is what I am trying to create. Here is the link in case you can't find the picture: https://anatomypubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ar.23569#:~:text=Defining%20the%20Morphology%20of%20Adult,90%25%20of%20the%20total%20saliva.

Comment: Hi, Kay.. Nothing labelled 'Lumen' in the illustration. I take it that's the lining. Do you need the cellular structure represented? Just the surface, or the side-walls, of cells? Is this for illustration, or for 3D printing?